# php render text on image with preview

Tags: php, image, text, render, preview

can anyone recommend a tutorial or library that can address the issue
of rendering a text onto a image with a preview option? the idea is to present the user with a picture onto which they can add text of their choosing. after viewing a preview they can submit it.
a know that php's imagettftext can handle this and a have some ajax experience. i was hoping that
a complete or close to complete solution is already in existence.
[here a similar app](http://builder.cheezburger.com/builder/#step2_6202782976,http://i.chzbgr.com/imagestore/2012/5/7/4b62c954-d747-40ed-a9a3-816f71cd205a.jpg)
thanks in advance for any attempt to assist and have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Adding text to images in realtime](http://blog.doh.ms/2008/02/12/adding-text-to-images-in-real-time-with-php/)